# Load multiple Excel sheets using For loop with QlikView

Tags: qlikview

I want to load data from two different Excel files, and use them in the same table in QlikView.

I have two files (DIVISION.xls and REGION.xls), and I'm using the following code:

```
let tt = 'DIVISION$' and 'REGION$';

FOR Each db_schema in 'DIVISION.xls','REGION.xls'
    FOR Each v_db in $(tt)
        div_reg_table:
        LOAD *
        FROM $(db_schema) 
        (biff, embedded labels, table is $(v_db));
    NEXT
NEXT
```

This code works fine, and does not show any error, but I don't get any data, and I don't see my new table (`div_reg_table`).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason that your code does not load any data is due to the form of the `tt` variable.

When your inner loop executes, it evaluates `tt` (denoted by `$(tt)`), which then results in the evaluation of:

```
'DIVISION$' AND 'REGION$'
```

Which results in null, since these are just two strings.

If you change your statement slightly, from `LET` to `SET` and remove the `AND`, then the inner loop will work. For example:

```
SET tt = 'DIVISION$', 'REGION$';
```

However, this also now means that your inner loop will be executed for each value in `tt` for *both* workbooks. This means that unless you have a `REGION` sheet in your `DIVISION` workbook, then the load will fail.

To avoid this, you may wish to restructure your script slightly so that you have a control table which details the files and tables to load. An example I prepared is shown below:

```
FileList:
LOAD * INLINE [
    FileName, TableName
    REGION.XLS, REGION$
    DIVISION.XLS, DIVISION$
];


FOR i = 0 TO NoOfRows('FileList') - 1

    LET FileName = peek('FileName', i, 'FileList'); 
    LET TableName = peek('TableName', i, 'FileList'); 

    div_reg_table:
    LOAD
        *
    FROM '$(FileName)'
    (biff, embedded labels, table is '$(TableName)');

NEXT
```

---

If you have just two files `DIVISION.XLS` and `REGION.XLS` then it may be worth just using two separate loads one after the other, and removing the for loop entirely. For example:

```
div_reg_table:
LOAD
    *
FROM [DIVISION.XLS]
(biff, embedded labels, table is DIVISION$)
WHERE DivisionName = 'AA';

LOAD
    *
FROM [REGION.XLS]
(biff, embedded labels, table is REGION$)
WHERE RegionName = 'BB';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i just want to know how can i specify the links to the files 'DIVISION.XLS' and 'REGION.XLS'

Comment: It's good for the links now, but it didn't work, i get this error : Cannot locate table in BIFF file
div_reg_table:
    LOAD
        *
    FROM 'REGION.XLS'
    (biff, embedded labels, table is 'REGION')

Comment: @ANAS89 The reason for this is that QV expects Excel sheet names to end with `$`. I've now changed that in the `FileList` table.

Comment: It works very well, thank you, the only problem is that i can't use the fields of the two tables in a where clause for example, it shows me an error that the fields are unfounded, after all that's the goal of doing this :(

Comment: @ANAS89 Could you please give some more detail? Which fields are these? Could you provide a sample of what you're doing with your where clause? Thank you.

Comment: In the file REGION.XLS, i have two fields : RegionCode and RegionName. and in the file DIVISION.XLS i have also two fields: DivisionCode and DivisionName. i want to use them in the where clause, for example if i want show date of DivisionName = 'AA' and RegionName= 'BB'. but it didn't works, i want to merge the two files into one.

Comment: @ANAS89 In this case, if you have just two source data files, it might be worth just loading them one after another rather than using a loop so that you can specify your where clause for each. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to make the noofrows('Filelist') test be 1 less than the answer.

noofrows('filelist') will evaluate to 2 so you will get a loop step for 0,1 and 2. So 2 will return a null which will cause it to fail.

I did it like this:

FileList:
LOAD * INLINE [
    FileName, TableName
    REGION.XLS, REGION
    DIVISION.XLS, DIVISION
];

let vNo= NoOfRows('FileList')-1;

FOR i = 0 TO $(vNo)

```
LET FileName = peek('FileName', i, 'FileList'); 
LET TableName = peek('TableName', i, 'FileList'); 

div_reg_table:
LOAD
    *,
    $(i) as I,
    FileBaseName() as SOURCE
FROM '$(FileName)'
(biff, embedded labels, table is '$(TableName)');
```

NEXT